# error when I try to make project on fire base

Tags: android, firebase

It keep telling me
File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
 Searched Location:

```
C:\Users\lolic\AndroidStudioProjects\FireBaseTest\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\lolic\AndroidStudioProjects\FireBaseTest\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
C:\Users\lolic\AndroidStudioProjects\FireBaseTest\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
C:\Users\lolic\AndroidStudioProjects\FireBaseTest\app\src\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\lolic\AndroidStudioProjects\FireBaseTest\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
C:\Users\lolic\AndroidStudioProjects\FireBaseTest\app\google-services.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download a google-services.json configuration file from Firebase for your project, you can do so from the Project Settings page. You then need to place this file in your Android app project folder to allow it to be detected.

See the [documentation here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) for more info.

Your project structure should look something like below:

```
FireBaseTest
---app
    ---google-services.json
    ---src
        ---main....
        ....
---build.gradle
---other files here....
```

Comment: File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
 Searched Location: 
C:\Users\lolic\AndroidStudioProjects\FireBaseTest\app\src\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\lolic\AndroidStudioProjects\FireBaseTest\app\google-services.json

Comment: @LarySamuel where did you put the .json file? It needs to be inside your app folder as stated by the error message: 
C:\Users\lolic\AndroidStudioProjects\FireBaseTest\app\google-services.json

Comment: when I put in src the error says
C:\Users\lolic\AndroidStudioProjects\FireBaseTest\app\src\debug\google-services.json
And when I put it in src it says 
C:\Users\lolic\AndroidStudioProjects\FireBaseTest\app\google-services.json

Comment: @LarySamuel it should be 1 level up from src, so within the app folder. I'll edit my answer to provide a view of the structure

Comment: I cant my  what ever I did 
it look like 
--app
    
    ---src
---google-services.json
        ---main....
        ....
---build.gradle
---other files here.
or
in scr file

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: @LarySamuel sorry, finding it hard to explain. Do you have the code on Github or something similar that I can look at and explain a bit clearer?

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lolic.firebasetest"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: and if I am right the error in this line apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate google-services.json from the Firebase console and then manually copy google-services.json into your app folder.

Comment: I did it before but still have the same error
File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. Searched Location: C:\Users\lolic\AndroidStudioProjects\FireBaseTest\app\src\debug\google-services.json C:\Users\lolic\AndroidStudioProjects\FireBaseTest\app\google-services.json